# Create list items for array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of objects:

```
myArray = [Object { orderNum="A000", userName="Oswaldo", value=504.74, more...}, Object { orderNum="A001", userName="Mao", value=529.17, more...}, Object { orderNum="A002", userName="Angeline", value=553.6, more...}, Object { orderNum="A003", userName="Gerardo", value=578.03, more...}]
```

I am trying to loop over it and get each object's contents into a list item. I use this:

```
jQuery.each(Top5SalesOrders , function(index, value){
      $('.mylist').append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
});
```

But I am getting [object Object] in my list items.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, as second parameter of callback function is `Object`, thus you have to use `obj.value` to access the `value` property of object.

*Use*

```
jQuery.each(Top5SalesOrders , function(index, obj){
      $('.mylist').append('<li>' + obj.value+ '</li>');
});
```

Comment: It showed the value property of the object, not the whole object contents, as i was expecting, but this way also allowed me to show other stuff, using the same pattern: obj.orderNum, obj.userName, etc. 

So thanks!